# redindexer not running via exec

Tags: php, magmi, indexer

I wrote a custom script to force magmi to import data during a cron job, now I need to force reindexing. I tried using the magmi module but it didn't work so I'm running it manually.

```
passthru("php -f ".$config['shell']."/indexer.php -- --reindexall");
```

All passthru outputs is Content-type: text/html

This is driving me crazy, anyone have an idea about this? reindexer runs finevia command line, I have tried exec, there are no restricted functions.

Comment: Not related to Magento directly.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do in this situation is not to try and execute an PHP file from your script Magento have provided a means for us to reindex programatically.

I am assuming that your script has access to Mage:: but if not ensure that you

```
require('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
```

We can then choose to reindex all or index individual processes, As you have indicated that you want to reindex all you would use:

```
   for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load($i);
    $process->reindexAll();
   }
```

I prefer to use this method as you can add the index process in a try catch you can add more controlled Mage::log() to ensure indexing has been triggered etc.